# Javascript Regex matching option string

Tags: javascript, css, regex

I'm trying to match on CSS inline style on both cases

```
width: 55px;
```

or

```
width: calc(100% - 10px);
```

For now I can solve the first case, and get part of second case with:

```
/^width:\s*(calc\()*(([-+]?([0-9]*\.)?[0-9]*)(px|em|ex|%|in|cm|mm|pt|pc))/i
```

See the live example: http://regexr.com?371o0

Thanks in advance

Comment: what about `width:0;` zero can be without any unit.

Comment: Can we know why? Are you trying to capture something or you just want to validate if it's a valid width declaration?

Comment: Maybe `(width: ([^;]*))` would be enough ?

Comment: I'm working on Select2 jquery plugin - on method `initContainerWidth` I get this validation

Comment: @Brewal thanks - for now I will disable validation and use this approach. Create a answer than I will accept

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply use the following regex to capture the `width` declaration:

```
'font-size:10px; width: 1px;'.match(/\bwidth:([^;]*)/i) 
//["width: 1px;", " 1px"]
```

Then if you want to validate it, you could simply do something like:

```
function isValidCSSWidth(value) {
    var el = document.createElement('div'),
        style = el.style;

    style.width = value;

    return !!style.width.length;
}

isValidCSSWidth('calc(100% - 10px)'); //true
isValidCSSWidth('0'); //true
isValidCSSWidth('invalid'); //false
```

Answer (score 1):

The following would actually match both lines, but I don't like it very much as you should use a parser for this:

```
^width:\s*(?:calc\()?(?:[0-9]+(?:p[ctx]|e[mx]|%|in|[cm]m)[\s+-]*)+\)?
```

[Regex101 Demo](http://regex101.com/r/eX8yV2)

Comment: Especially when there's already a built-in parser ;) See my answer.

Comment: @plalx You're totally correct. I don't like to use a regular expression to accomplish what a parser should do. +1 for your clever method to validate.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done with a single regex, albeit a rather complicated one:

```
^width:\s*((?:calc\((\s*[-+]?\s*[0-9]+(px|em|ex|%|in|cm|mm|pt|pc)+)+\)\s*;$)|(\s*[-+]?\s*[0-9]+(px|em|ex|%|in|cm|mm|pt|pc)+)\s*;)$
```

This matches both your examples and some other 'width' CSS declarations I could think of.

(Edit: I corrected it to now always check for closing ) when calc is present).

Comment: On second thought the lookahead `?:` could be removed now.